# Beginner's Java Help IF/THEN statements?

Tags: java

I need to create a program that allows users to create their own colony of amoebas. One of the requirements is to include giving them vitamins and sickness.

Vitamins – Vitamins can help our amoebas stay healthy. Ask your user if they want to give their colony vitamins.

Sickness – Unfortunately, all pets sometimes get sick. When that happens, 10% of the amoebas die off. For every session:

If the colony is NOT given vitamins, it has a 25% chance that it may get sick.

If the colony IS given vitamins, it has a 20% chance that it may get sick.

I used a random number generator to get the percentage of sickness, but for some reason there is something wrog with my if/then statements because it never makes sickness equal to true, it always makes it equal to false and I have it set to boolean and declared some of my if/then statements to make sickness equal to false.

EDIT: I listed the code below instead of the links, and I added the code that luisluix provided and that seems to be working now.

My codes are below:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AmoebaColony {

private String colonyName;
private String caretakerName;;
private String isItSick;
private int daysFed;
private int breedRequest;
private int breedSuccess;
private int rNumber;
private int requestVitamins;
private double startingSize;
private double colonySize;
private double finalSize;
private double died;
private boolean sickness;
private boolean vitamin;

public void setColonyProperties()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome new caretaker, this program allows you to create, manage, and develope your own amoeba colony.",
    "Welcome!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    colonyName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of your amoeba colony.",
    "Creating Your Amoeba Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    caretakerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of your amoeba colony's caretaker.",
    "Creating Your Amoeba Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    startingSize = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the starting size of your amoeba colony.",
    "Creating Your Amoeba Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
}

public void setUserActions()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, " + colonyName + " is starting out great with a totoal of " + startingSize + " amoebas.",
    "Your New Amoeba Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now that you've got your colony set up, you can do several things to it, including feeding, breeding, and giving it vitamins.",
    "Developing Your Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    daysFed = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Feeding your colony allows it to breed, for each day fed, it can breed one time. How many days would you like to feed your colony?",
    "Feeding Your Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    breedRequest = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Breeding allows you to increase the size of your colony. A colony must be fed in order to breed. \nYour colony size will double for each successful breed. How many time would you like your colony to breed?",
    "Breeding Your Amoeba Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
}

public void setVitamin()
{
    requestVitamins = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Giving your colony vitamins decreases the chance of your amoebas getting sick and dying off. Would you like to give your colony vitamins?",
    "Keeping Your Colony Healthy",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);     
}

public void vitaminResult()
{
    if (requestVitamins == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
        vitamin = true;           
    else 
        vitamin = false; 
}

public void setBreeding()
{
    if (daysFed >= breedRequest)
        breedSuccess = breedRequest;
    else
        breedSuccess = daysFed;

    colonySize = startingSize;
    colonySize *= Math.pow(2, breedSuccess);
}

public void getSick()
{
    Random number = new Random();        
    rNumber = number.nextInt(100);

    if (vitamin == true)
    {
        if (rNumber <= 20)
            sickness = true;
        else
            sickness = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (rNumber <= 25)
            sickness = true;
        else
            sickness = false;
    }
}

public void sickEffect()
{         
    if (sickness == true)
        finalSize = colonySize*.10;
    else
        finalSize = colonySize;
}

public void deadCount()
{
    died = finalSize - colonySize;
}

public void setSickText()
{
    if (sickness == true)
        isItSick = "Yes";
    else
        isItSick = "No";
}

public void getFinalDialogOutput()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rNumber + " All actions have been completed. \n\n Colony Name: " + colonyName + "\n Caretaker Name: " + caretakerName + "\n Starting Size: " + startingSize + "\n Number of of times fed in days: " + daysFed + "\n Number of times requested to breed: " + breedRequest + "\n Number of successful breeds: " + breedSuccess + "\n Sickness and death: " + isItSick + ", " + died + " died" + "\n  Final size of colony: " + finalSize, "Amoeba Colony Summary", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

and test class here

```
public class AmoebaColonyTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AmoebaColony newColony = new AmoebaColony();

    newColony.setColonyProperties();
    newColony.setUserActions();
    newColony.setVitamin();
    newColony.setBreeding();
    newColony.getSick();
    newColony.sickEffect();
    newColony.deadCount();
    newColony.setSickText();
    newColony.getFinalDialogOutput();

}
}
```

Comment: @clcto ok sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Note that you never call `vitaminResult` but anyway I ran your original code and they do get sick sometimes. I don't know what the problem is if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

assuming it isnt a logic error, my guess would be to always use curly brackets to make sure if statements execute properly. Also, you are working with random numbers, you still have 1/5 for your stuff to get sick. make sure you do multiple iterations and print rNumber.

```
if (vitamin == true && rNumber <= 20)
        sickness = true;

    else if (vitamin == false && rNumber <= 25)
        sickness = true;

    else
        sickness = false;
```

try it like this:

```
   if (vitamin == true && rNumber <= 20){
        sickness = true;
   }
    else if (vitamin == false && rNumber <= 25){
        sickness = true;
   }
    else{
        sickness = false;
   }
```

Comment: Ok, I did that, thank you. But when I generated a number of 33, it said that sickness was false, and in the output, isItSick was set to "No" and 0 died, when it should have been "Yes" and "# died"

Comment: thats ok, your if statement only makes them sick if rNumber less than or equal to 20 or 25

Comment: Ah ok, right. Thanks for that code fix, it seems to be working now. I just need to fix the math mistake I made lol, it gave me negatives for dead and final size :P Thank you.